# Relation column name with row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `RedMarkSubcategory` like:

```
+----------------------+--------+-----------+
| RedMarkSubcategoryId |  Name  | IsDeleted |
+----------------------+--------+-----------+
|                    1 | Item 1 |         0 |
|                    2 | Item 2 |         0 |
|                    3 | Item 3 |         0 |
+----------------------+--------+-----------+
```

And I have another table called `RedMarkItems` with columns sich as `RedMarkSubcategoryId` - like this:

```
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+
| RedMArkItemsId | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+
|              1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|              2 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|              3 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

As you can see columns are created but without space. My question is, is there any way to relate these two tables in order to get a result like:

```
SELECT 
    [RS].[Name], RI.* 
FROM
    RedMarkSubcategory AS RS
INNER JOIN 
    RedMarkItems AS [RI] ON RS.Name = "RI.columnName" 
WHERE 
    RS.IsDeleted = 0
```

Comment: Please provide the results you want.

Comment: My desire result is to know what items are checked where isdeleted = 0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can `join` the tables and then extract the values.  For instance:

```
SELECT [RS].[Name],
       (CASE WHEN RS.NAME = 'Item 1' THEN RI.item1
             WHEN RS.NAME = 'Item 2' THEN RI.item2
             WHEN RS.NAME = 'Item 3' THEN RI.item3
        END) as ri_value
FROM RedMarkSubcategory RS INNER JOIN
     RedMarkItems RI
     ON RS.Name IN ('Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3')
WHERE RS.IsDeleted = 0
```

Comment: Oooh but supossing I dont know names of columns? I know they are always the same without spaces , but I dont know names

Comment: Because user created it dinamically, for example, if I add new row to redmarksubcategory table it be added as column in RedMarkItems table, tha's how it works. My desire result is to know what items are checked where isdeleted = 0